# Pasar variables de la funcion principal a otra

Tags: c++

Tengo este código, el cual permite al usuario ingresar una cantidad de números indefinida. Cuando el usuario presione 0 el programa se debe detener y mostrar cosas como: la cantidad de veces que se realizó el proceso, el promedio de los números ingresados, pero principalmente, decir cual de todos los números que están allí es mayor o menor. La cuestión es que el programa es con funciones.

En la función principal probé con colocar el procedimiento para guardar los datos en las variables, y en la otra función, imprimir el resultado de las mismas. El problema está en que cuando llamo a la segunda función, ésta no muestra nada, me imagino que es porque tengo que pasar los valores de las variables a dicha función, más sin embargo he intentado de todo, y no consigo hacerlo.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdlib.h>
using namespace std;

void imprimir( ) {

}

int main( ) {
  int n, c = 0, s = 0, max = 0, min = 1000000;

  do {
    cout << "Ingrese un numero (0 es para salir) :";
    cin >> n; 

    if( n != 0 ) {
      c++;
      s += n;

      if( n > max ) {
        max = n;
      }

      if( n < min ) {
        min = n;    
      }
    } 
  } while( n != 0 );

  imprimir( );
}

void imprimir( int n, int c, int s, int min, int max ) {
  n = n; c = c; s = s; min = min, max = max;

  cout << "La cantidad de datos es: "<< c << endl;
  cout << "El promedio de los datos es: " << s / c << endl;
  cout << "El mayor numero es: "<< max << endl;
  cout << "El menor numero es: " << min << endl;

  system( "pause" );
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Cosas que veo:

1. La forma de declarar tu función `imprimir()` no es la correcta.

En vez de esto:

```
void imprimir( ) {

}
```

Debe ser:

```
void imprimir( int, int, int, int, int );
```

Ten en cuenta que quieres pasar en este caso 5 `int`, por ello tienes que indicarlo.

2. Cuando llamas a la funcion imprimir(), le tienes que pasar los parámetros que quieres.

En vez de:

```
imprimir( );
```

Debes pasarle como parámetros tus variables:

```
imprimir( n, c, s, min, max );
```

Por ultimo en tu función `void imprimir( int n, int c, int s, int min, int max ) {`

No hace falta que hagas estas asignaciones: `n = n; c = c; s = s; min = min, max = max;`

Puedes utilizar las variables directamente.

**Código completo:**

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdlib.h>
using namespace std;

void imprimir(int,int,int,int,int );


int main( ) {
  int n, c = 0, s = 0, max = 0, min = 1000000;

  do {
    cout << "Ingrese un numero (0 es para salir) :";
    cin >> n; 

    if( n != 0 ) {
      c++;
      s += n;

      if( n > max ) {
        max = n;
      }

      if( n < min ) {
        min = n;    
      }
    } 
  } while( n != 0 );

  imprimir( n, c, s, min, max );
}

void imprimir( int n, int c, int s, int min, int max ) {
  //n = n; c = c; s = s; min = min, max = max;

  cout << "La cantidad de datos es: "<< c << endl;
  cout << "El promedio de los datos es: " << s / c << endl;
  cout << "El mayor numero es: "<< max << endl;
  cout << "El menor numero es: " << min << endl;

  system( "pause" );
}
```

Comment: Muchas gracias amigo, de verdad tenía como 3 días dandole la vuelta a eso y nada que lo conseguía :') muchas gracias de corazón u,u

Comment: @KronosjMendez Si mi respuesta, o la de mis compañeros, fue de utilidad, te sugiero leer [esto](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Comment: He leído el apartado, disculpa si presioné en la banderita, estaba buscando donde votar el comentario u,u, ya he aceptado la respuesta, y he leído todo, lo aplicaré en un futuro, un abrazo, y no debo decir gracias, pero de verdad lo agradezco

Answer (score 3):

Tienes dos funciones `imprimir`:

```
void imprimir( ) {

}

void imprimir( int n, int c, int s, int min, int max ) {
  n = n; c = c; s = s; min = min, max = max;

  cout << "La cantidad de datos es: "<< c << endl;
  cout << "El promedio de los datos es: " << s / c << endl;
  cout << "El mayor numero es: "<< max << endl;
  cout << "El menor numero es: " << min << endl;

  system( "pause" );
}
```

Y tu estás llamando justamente a la función que **no hace nada**. Fíjate que estás llamando a la función que **no recibe** argumentos:

```
  } while( n != 0 );

  imprimir( );
}
```

Lo que tienes que hacer en primer lugar es eliminar la función *inutil* para evitar errores tontos. Si pruebas a compilar sin esa función verás que salen errores en tiempo de compilación:

```
//  void imprimir() {
// }

void imprimir( int n, int c, int s, int min, int max ) {
  n = n; c = c; s = s; min = min, max = max;

  cout << "La cantidad de datos es: "<< c << endl;
  cout << "El promedio de los datos es: " << s / c << endl;
  cout << "El mayor numero es: "<< max << endl;
  cout << "El menor numero es: " << min << endl;

  system( "pause" );
}

int main( ) {
  int n, c = 0, s = 0, max = 0, min = 1000000;

  do {
    cout << "Ingrese un numero (0 es para salir) :";
    cin >> n; 

    if( n != 0 ) {
      c++;
      s += n;

      if( n > max ) {
        max = n;
      }

      if( n < min ) {
        min = n;    
      }
    } 
  } while( n != 0 );

  imprimir( ); // <<--- ERROR!!!
}
```

Ahora ya puedes centrarte en pasarle a la función correcta los valores que necesita.

Por otro lado fíjate que la primera línea de la función `imprimir` es totalmente innecesaria:

```
void imprimir( int n, int c, int s, int min, int max ) {
  n = n; c = c; s = s; min = min, max = max; // <<---
```

Los argumentos de una función son variables válidas y las puedes usar directamente:

```
void imprimir( int n, int c, int s, int min, int max ) {

  cout << "La cantidad de datos es: "<< c << endl;
  cout << "El promedio de los datos es: " << s / c << endl;
  cout << "El mayor numero es: "<< max << endl;
  cout << "El menor numero es: " << min << endl;

  system( "pause" );
}
```

Dos últimos apuntes:

- la división `s / c` puede darte resultados erróneos ya que la división entre dos enteros **no genera decimales**. Tienes que forzar a que al menos uno de los dos operandos sea decimal:

  ```
  cout << "El promedio de los datos es: " << static_cast<double>(s) / c << endl;
  ```
- La función **no usa** `n` en ningún momento. Si no es necesario ese argumento es mejor eliminarlo.

Answer (score 1):

Es normal que el programa no te muestre nada, porque estás llamando a una función que no hace nada:

```
void imprimir( ) {

}
```

Las líneas anteriores le dicen al compilador: "*Hay una función llamada `imprimir` que no recibe parámetros y que no devuelve nada*".

Fl final del programa creas **otra** función:

```
void imprimir( int n, int c, int s, int min, int max ) {
    // código
}
```

Las líneas anteriores le dicen al compilador: "*Hay una función llamda `imprimir` que recibe 5 parámetros y que no devuelve nada*".

Cuando haces una llamada  función como esta:

```
imprimir( );
```

Le estás diciendo al compilador: "*Llama a la función llamada `imprimir` que no recibe parámetros*" ¿Qué función `imprimir` crees que llamrá? Obviamente la primera, que es la que coincide con los parámetros que le pasas.